# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un objeto enviado como parámetro desde una referencia en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo dos proyectos en vb.net en ambos tengo una clase para conexión a base de datos, en ambos proyectos la clase es idéntica.
El objeto de la conexión lo quiero enviar como parámetro a un formulario dentro de otro proyecto y convertirlo en la clase del lado de ese proyecto, pero no me deja hacer cast, aunque sean idénticas las clases al parecer me toma como si fueran diferentes por estar en diferentes proyectos.

Con éste ejemplo explico ya que información confidencial y no puedo compartirla.

Proyecto1

```
Private Sub BtnAbrir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAbrir.Click
    Dim _conexionProyecto1 As New ConexionProyecto1()
    Dim _formProyecto2 As New Proyecto2.FormProyecto2(DirectCast(_conexionProyecto1, Object))
End Sub
```

Proyecto2

```
Public Sub New(ByVal _conexionProyecto1 As Object)


    InitializeComponent()

    Dim _conexionProyecto2 As New ConexionProyecto2()

    _conexionProyecto2 = DirectCast(_conexionProyecto1, ConexionProyecto2)

End Sub
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que puedo recomendarte es que no definas ninguna clase de conexion, sino que uses el `app.config` para definir la conexion y tomarla usano las clase `ConfigurationManager`.
De esta forma ambos proyectos pueden acceder a la configuracion sin duplicar clases.

Ahora bien si se trata de una clase con funcionalidad comun podrias llevar esta a un tercer proyecto que sera comun a los otros dos, seria un proyecto del tipo `Class Library`, alli defines la clase y luego la referencias en los otros dos proyectos para poder utilizarla.

Primero realizas la referencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando el proyecto comun que quieres referenciar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo esto podras instanciar la clase comun que definas y reutilizar la funcionalidad

Nota: las imagenes son de ejemplo para entender como referencias los proyectos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo que sucede es que por funcionalidad del sistema, cada proyecto debe contener esa clase, yo lo haría como me dices, pero es cosa de la empresa. Saludos.

Comment: Pero entonces cada clase sera diferente a la otra, no podras reusar codigo a menos que implementes herencia, con esta podrias crear una clase base que definan las clases de cada proyecto

Comment: Creo que lo más conveniente será que mande parámetros de la conexión al final, ya que es como dices, las clases son diferentes por de dónde se toman.